# Python Webbot: How can I tell him to push this button?

Tags: python, webbot

I am currently trying to run this line of code with Webbot in Python

```
from webbot import Browser
bot = Browser()
bot.click(classname = "pageChangeNext")
```

in order to push this button, but it won't press it.

```html
<img src="/bilder/design/gra_pfeil_rechts_nor.jpg" class="pageChangeNext" onclick="bookINIT(1)"> == $0
```

It actually logs me out, but I don't want it to do that just yet.
I'm very desperate right now, as the whole website heavily relies on JavaScript and I can't get it.

How would you guys refer to this button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an image , you must specify that `img` tag in your click function call , like this :

```
web.click(classname = 'mypassword' , tag = 'img' )
```

```html
<img src="/bilder/design/gra_pfeil_rechts_nor.jpg" class="pageChangeNext" onclick="bookINIT(1)"> == $0
```